# Junk in my downloads folder Windows 10

Tags: windows

I have random files in my downloads folder. Their names are like u1,u2... Is it safe to delete them?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5injB.png)

Comment: You can try to open them in Notepad to see if there's any identifying information.  They might be actual downloads that misnamed or renamed, or they might have been unpacked from a compressed file that was downloaded, or they might be temporary files created by a program and for some reason saved to the Downloads folder.  You might be able to figure out what they were by looking at the dates.

Comment: Some is nonsense, some is xml

Comment: do the xml field names give some clue?

Comment: nope, they just say u1,u2,u3...

Answer (score 1):

If they  have some file extensions like .opdownload or .crdownload or anything like opera web document, it is completely safe to delete them. They are incomplete downloads caused due to technical errors..
Check the file type.

Comment: they dont have a file extension

Comment: files cant exist without an extension..please check your view tab and enable file extensions

Comment: They have a type File, there is nothing after the dot